# Add auto number column to list view table?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I've a ListView that fetch data from SQL compact CE database. I've an ID column in the database already , but **I want to add an auto number column in the list view itself.**

I want to replace the ID column with an auto number column **(I don't want the number to be saved in the database itself , I just want to sort the rows in the list view)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/samEh.jpg

The code I'm using :

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(sqldr["ID"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["EnglishWord"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["EnglishDesc"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["ArabicDesc"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["ArabicWord"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["Subject"].ToString());


                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

I'm using C# - Windows Application - WinForms

Comment: Why do you want to replace the ID column with an auto increment column?

Comment: @JunaidKirkire Just to sort the list for the user, so let's say if the search result shows 100 rows , I need them to be numbered from 1-100 , rather than showing records IDs in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ListViewItem item = listView.Items.Add((listView.Items.Count + 1).ToString());
```

However the problem here is you may get duplicate numbers if you add/remove, if you did this in one go never to be repeated it'd be less of an issue.

To avoid this you'd probably need some kind of class global counter, and then do:

```
int counter = 0;

ListViewItem item = listView.Items.Add((++counter).ToString());
```

This would ensure that any new addition to the list will get the next number up, so it's always increasing.

Comment: Perfect answer , exactly to the point. I wish I could add reputation. Thanks a lot.